# Cannot delete the null tuple using sql command

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table where in the the attriubtes are usn name outtime.
the values for

```
       usn=222;
       name=xyz;
       outtime=NULL;
```

when i query using

```
delete from table_1 where outtime=' ';
```

nothing happens.

But when i query using
`delete from table_1 where outtime!=' ';`
it just works fine
WHY IS IT SO?
THE `DATATYPE FOR` `OUTTIME` IS `nchar(10)`;

Comment: `null is not equal to empty string ('')` that is why. Use `where outlime is null`

Comment: @Kaf: The result of `null <> ''` is `unknown`.  A query like `delete YourTable where col1 <> ''` would not remove rows where `col1` is `null`.

Comment: is it sql server or mysql?

Comment: @Kaf: The statement `null <> ''` is not `true`, it's `unknown`. `null` is neither equal to, nor not equal to `''`

Comment: @Andomar, precisely !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NULL and blank are different.  Use this:

```
DELETE FROM table_1 WHERE outtime IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the empty string `' '` is not the same as a `NULL` value.

Null implies an unknown value, where as `' '` is the value of the empty string.  If you want to remove all values that are null try something like:

```
delete from table_1 where outtime is null
```